# Grails, how to get the request object

Tags: grails

Grails has a request object which is defined [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html).

The problem is when I try to use it, I get:

```
No such property: request for class:xxx
```

Reading the first 100 hits googling this error only produced one suggestion:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes
:
def my() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
}
```

However, this gives:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: RequestContextHolder for class: net.ohds.ReportService
```

1. How does one get a handle on the request object in Grails?
2. How do you find out about this?  So few people have asked this question, it must be documented somewhere, or in some example, but I can't find either.

Comment: why do you want request object in service?

Answer (score 20):

In Grails 3.0, from a **service** get the `request` object using:

**grails-app/services/com/example/MyService.groovy**

```
import org.grails.web.util.WebUtils
...
def request = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getCurrentRequest()
def ip = request.getRemoteAddr()
```

*Documentation:*
https://docs.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/web/util/WebUtils.html#retrieveGrailsWebRequest()

*Note:*
The old `codehaus` package has been deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

Try following code:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils

...

GrailsWebRequest webUtils = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
def request = webUtils.getCurrentRequest()
```

Comment: I also got the same thing from here http://amitpatelinfo.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/getting-requestresponse-in-grails-service-class/

Comment: I'm still using Grails 2.5.6 (I know this is old and outdated). The code in this answer works for this version of Grails.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you probably got "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: RequestContextHolder for class: net.ohds.ReportService" because you didn't import the "org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder" class in your ReportService.

The most common place to want access to the request object is in a controller.  From a controller you simply refer to the `request` property and it will be there.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/request.html.

The answer to how to access the request object from somewhere else may depend on what the somewhere else is.

**UPDATE**

I don't know why you are having trouble passing the request from a controller to a service, but you can.  I suspect you are invoking the method incorrectly, but something like this will work...

```
// grails-app/services/com/demo/HelperService.groovy
package com.demo

class HelperService {

    // you don't have to statically type the
    // argument here... but you can
    def doSomethingWithRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest req) {
        // do whatever you want to do with req here...
    }
}
```

A controller...

```
// grails-app/controllers/com/demo/DemoController.groovy
package com.demo

class DemoController {

    def helperService

    def index() {
        helperService.doSomethingWithRequest request
        render 'Success'
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I see the problem, in grails, the request is only avaiable in the controller.  I want to create a utility function which returnts the IP.  As there are only views, controllers, domains, and services, I am trying to the utility in a service.  I tried passing the request to the service, but this doesnt work either, in the service I declare "def getIp( HttpServletRequest request) {" but then I get this error:  No signature of method: static net.me.UtilsService.getIp()is applicable for argument types: (org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3Security..

Comment: @JohnLittle That is a peculiar statement but even if I submit that it is true, whatever you could do in Java with respect to this you could do here.  You can use Java in Grails.  It turns out that there is nothing that Java has to offer for this in particular that can't be done with Groovy, but you could use Java if that was what you wanted to do.

Comment: The problem in grails is I dont know the type of anything, and can't find it out.  Here, I am guessing that request is HttpServletRequest , but it isn't.  Stuff that available in controllers are not available in other places, and to find out how to get it is very difficult.

Comment: @JohnLittle `getIp( HttpServletRequest request)` expects `HttpServletRequest` but you're passing `HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3‌​Security`. Are your sure that it's same class?

Comment: @JohnLittle did you try to `import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder` in your service as Jeff suggested?

Comment: "Here, I am guessing that request is HttpServletRequest, but it isn't".  That is not correct.  The request object is an instance of a class which implements HttpServletRequest.

Comment: I edited the answer above to include a code sample of passing the request to a service.