# getting the request in Grails service

Tags: grails, grails-services

In **Grails Service** i'm trying to get the request but i'm getting the below error :

```
 No such property: theRequest for class:   com.sherif.utils.MyService
```

here is my code in the service:

```
def theRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getCurrentRequest()
```

anything missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Something must be wrong with where you are declaring `theRequest`, can you post more context?

Comment: @doelleri it was declared inside the method

Comment: Why do you need request in grails service? It's a bad practice to access request in service. You should instead do everything with your request in controller itself.

Comment: Take a look at the following. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756628/grails-how-to-get-the-request-object

Answer (score 0):

You might try this instead:

```
def getTheRequest() {
    WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getCurrentRequest()
}
```

You should be able to call that the same way as a property:

```
myService.theRequest
```